# How to relate a list with custum button in ribbon? Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, development

I have created a custum button called `Custom Button` in my ribbon I have also created a `Ribbon Tab` to keep my ribbon more organized. I have 2 list one is called `empribbon` and second  is called `Child`

Now the ribbon is implemeted on my `empribbon` list, so my button `Custom Button` is only in my `empribbon` list, and If I click `Custom Button` I want my `Child` list to be displayed in this postion:

[image]

> Note I have enabled `dialog` for my `empribbon` list

Comment: What exactly from the child list would you like to be displayed in the highlighted area: the NewForm page of the child list, the default view of the child list, the settings page of the child list, etc? What exactly?

Comment: I want to display new form only

Comment: In that case, you should be able to make your ribbon button open the NewForm of the child list in a new/second modal dialog.

Comment: But I need to make it only within display

Comment: @MihailPopa how can I make with a click to display new form?

Comment: You can use the **CommandAction** attribute of the "CommandUIHandler" element to execute JavaScript when the ribbon button is clicked. (Example: http://www.a2zmenu.com/Tutorials/SharePoint/How-to-add-ribbon-button-in-SharePoint-list-and-library.aspx) See the following article for an official JS example on how to open a dialog with an existing page (e.g. NewForm.aspx): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @MihailPopa yes but can you tell me the javascript code to open the new form of my list?